# Ловить событие телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Прошу помочь по телеграм боту

```
InlineKeyboardButton(
      text="✅ Добавить в корзину",                                          
      callback_data='2',
InlineKeyboardButton(
      text="❌ Удалить из корзины",
      callback_data='3',
 )
```

Возникает проблема, как мне ловить событие кнопок по тексту а не по callback, когда я кликаю я получаю обе варианта

```
call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0]
```

прошу помочь

вот код обработчика

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def byuing_pear(call: CallbackQuery):
print(call.message)
    if call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][0].text == '✅ Добавить в корзину':
        product_id = call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][0].callback_data
        print('0')
        await call.message.answer(call.message)
    elif call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][0].text == '❌ Удалить из корзины':
        product_id = call.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][0].callback_data
        print('1')
```

Comment: А как Вы пробуете и где код Вашего обработчика?

Comment: @MyZik добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас логика построения приложения неправильная. Зачем Вам обрабатывать текст кнопки, когда есть уникальный идентификатор `callback_data`?

Плюс вот это:
`@dp.callback_query_handler()` значит, что абсолютно все коллбэки будут приходить в эту функцию, а оно вам надо? :)

Вместо этого используйте декоратор так: `@dp.callback_query_handler(text='1')`

Это значит, что эта функция запустится только тогда, когда `callback_data` у нажатой пользователем кнопки = `1`.

---

Плохо, когда одна функция (или обработчик, в Вашем случае) выполняет больше одной задачи - в Вашем случае, добавление и удаление с корзины.

Хорошо, когда логика разделена:

```py
cart_cb = CallbackData("Cart", "product_id", "action")

# Тут измените кнопки на свои, я просто привёл пример, как лучше назвать callback_data
buttons = [
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="✅ Добавить в корзину", callback_data=cart_cb.new(product_id=123, action="add")),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="❌ Удалить из корзины", callback_data=cart_cb.new(product_id=123, action="delete"))
]

...


@dp.callback_query_handler(cart_cb.filter(action=["add"]))
async def add_to_cart_handler(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    product_id = int(callback_data.get("product_id")) # 123
    print('Сработало нажатие на кнопку "Добавить в корзину!"')
    
    # Здесь Ваша логика на добавление товара в корзину


@dp.callback_query_handler(cart_cb.filter(action=["delete"]))
async def delete_from_cart_handler(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    product_id = int(callback_data.get("product_id")) # 123
    print('Сработало нажатие на кнопку "Удалить из корзины!"')

    # Здесь Ваша логика на удаление товара из корзины
```

P.S. В примере используется фабрика коллбэков от aiogram, это очень удобно и практично, почитать подробнее можете [здесь](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/buttons/#_5).

Comment: да я тоже так думал, но я внутрь callback_data писал идентификаторы товаров что бы в базе найти что то сними делать, и кнопки у меня генерятся, заранее не написано в коде

Comment: Ну так, ответ помог или нет?

Comment: Ответ не помог, потому что мы ловим по callback data, проблема в том что я сам генерирую callback_data, просто конкретного значение нет, а для каждого коллбека создать функции это не реально, и мне потребоволось лучше ловить по тексту, так как они только два варианта

Comment: Обновил пример для Вас. Вместо 123 в кнопках подставьте Ваш айди, где Вы там его получаете :)

Comment: ЕСТЬ! вы мне очень помогли, спасибо большое !

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь :)